# Maven "archetype:generate" cannot find my custom archetype, but can from interactive mode

Tags: java, maven, powershell, maven-3, maven-archetype

I have created a maven archetype by following the [maven official example](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html). I installed my custom archetype into my local repository using the command `mvn clean install` successfully. However, when I try to create a new project from the archetype using the following:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local -DarchetypeGroupId=aki.aboodz.archetype -DarchetypeArtifactId=my-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -DgroupId=com.test.custom.archetype -DartifactId=archetype-example -Dversion=1.0
```

I get project pom not found exception `MissingProjectException`. However, when enter the command `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local`, which lists all archetypes in interactive mode, I find my archetype installed there. That means I can only create a project using the interactive mode.

I believe there is something wrong in my maven configuration.

PS: I tried to create a project from [spring-quick-start](https://github.com/kolorobot/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype) archetype, I get the same issue. I can only do it from the interactive mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem is from entering the command using Windows PowerShell. PowerShell expects parameters to be inside quote (double/single quotes doesn't matter) if they contain special characters (e.g. '-' or '.'). When I tried executing the above command using cygwin, the command ran successfully, and created a project from the specified archetype without complaining. To execute the above command in Windows PowerShell, we need to quote our parameters values. The command will be as follows:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog="local" -DarchetypeGroupId="aki.aboodz.archetype" -DarchetypeArtifactId="my-archetype" -DarchetypeVersion="1.0-SNAPSHOT" -DgroupId="com.test.custom.archetype" -DartifactId="archetype-example" -Dversion="1.0"
```